# Convert a dictionary into a list of tuples

Tags: python, list, dictionary, tuples

Given a dictionary like this:

```
dic = {(7, 3): 18.51, (1, 3): 18.751, (5, 6): 34.917, (9, 8): 18.9738}
```

I want to convert it to a list of tuples like this:

```
my_list = [(7, 3, 18.51), (1, 3, 18.751), (5, 6, 34.917), (9, 8, 18.9738)]
```

I could have used a loop but I wonder if there is a neat way to do so instead of loops.

Comment: What have you tried and what is the problem with it? `.items()` alone gets you most of the way there.

Answer (score 5):

Simply use `list(..)` on some generator:

```
my_list = list(key+(val,) for key,val in dic.items())
```

This works since:

- [`list(..)`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/functions.html#func-list) takes as input an iterable and converts it to a list; and
- `key+(val,) for key,val dic.items()` is a generator that takes a pair of key-values of `dic` and transforms it into a tuple appending the `val` to the `key`.

Since we use a generator for a list, we can simplify this with *list comprehension*:

```
my_list = [key+(val,) for key,val in dic.items()]
```

Finally mind that **the order in which the tuples occur is not fixed** this is because the order how a `dict` stores elements is not fixed as well.

Comment: No, that won't quite meet the OP's requirements. They have two-tuple keys and want a three-tuple output `(k1, k2, v)`

Comment: @jonrsharpe: I see, perhaps a more generic way is to use `+` since it could be possible that the key contains more items.

Comment: @Don.C: see updated answer. With thanks to jonrsharpe for the comment.