# convert a dict into a (const) tuple of tuples

Tags: python, dictionary, tuples, constants

I want to convert a dict to a tuple of tuples

```
from typing import Dict, Tuple
class Data:
    def __init__(self, d: Dict[int, str]) -> None:
        self.data: Tuple[Tuple[int, str], ...] = ()
        for k, v in d.items():
            self.data += ((k, v),)

d = Data({5: "five", 4: "four"})
print(d.data)
```

This is somewhat similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41794757/convert-a-dictionary-into-a-list-of-tuples), but not identical. The reason I prefer a tuple of tuples is for const-ness. Is there a better way (or more pythonic) to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that this question is probably a duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16940293/why-is-there-no-tuple-comprehension-in-python), and the fourth answer there ([@Tom](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8548654/tom)) states it's fastest to do *tuple construction* of *list comprehension*:

```
self.data: Tuple[Tuple[int, str], ...] = tuple([(k, v) for k, v in d.items()])
```

Answer (score 2):

You could do `tuple(d.items())`.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
myDict = {5:"five",4:"four"}

def dictToTuple(d):
   return tuple(d.items())

print(dictToTuple(myDict))
```